# File upload in IOS safari browser

Tags: android, ios, browser, file-upload, safari

In my web app, User need to upload doc or pdf file from Mobile or Tablet browser [Android & IOS].

It's fine in Android, But IOS now allowing to access file system except images for uploading using safari.

I am searching for alternative ways and need solution without jail breaking, but i can't find one.

Comment: There's no way to upload other file types using Safari on iOS at the moment. Hopefully Apple will eventually implement the UIDocumentPickerViewController in their own app, it's ridiculous that they haven't yet.

Comment: @jjv360 Thanks, Is it possible in Hybrid App or Native App ?